# Hiding the google map infowindow content when multiple infowindows open at a time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to hide specific infoWindow content among multiple infowindows in google maps. If I open single infowindow it is working fine, but If I open multiple infowindows at a time content gets changed in the another infowindow.

Please find below code

```
 var map;
 var markers = [];

 function initMap() {
       map = new 
 google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
 zoom: 14,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.018057, 77.666794),
 mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
 disableDefaultUI: true
 });

  function addMarker(feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: feature.position,
  map: map,
  type: feature.type,
  id:feature.id,
  description: feature.description,
  infoWindow:new google.maps.InfoWindow({})
});

 marker.addListener('click', function() {

  var content="<h5>"+marker.type+"</h5>"+
             "<p id='des'>"+marker.description+"</p>"
             google.maps.event.addListener(this.infoWindow, 
         'domready', function () {
             if(marker.id===1){
             document.getElementById("des").style.display="none";
             }
          });
           this.infoWindow.setContent(content);
            this.infoWindow.open(map,marker);

       });
        markers.push(marker);
    }



  var features = [

{
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.018057, 77.666794),
  type: 'type1',
  id: 1,
  description: 'welcome to Hyd'
}, {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.015136, 77.647265),
  type: 'type2',
  id:2,
  description: ' welcome to Blr'
}, {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.009970, 77.660088),
  type: 'type3',
  id:3,
  description: ' welcome to Mum'
      }

    ];

     for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
         addMarker(features[i]);
        }
        }

     $(document).ready(function() {
         initMap();
     });
```

Please find below
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94y9ewsb/52/)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest fix is to use `this` inside the marker click event listener function to refer to the `marker` (the marker variable is left pointing to the last marker processed in the loop), then for the domready callback you need to save it (as `that`, in the callback function's closure)

Also, you have multiple infowindows with the same element id in them, element ids **have** to be unique.  One option is to append the marker id to the element id (i.e. `des1` for marker/infowindow 1).

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  // save this for use inside domready event listener callback function
  var that = this;
  var content = "<h5>" + this.type + "</h5>" +
    "<p id='des"+this.id+"'>" + this.description + "</p>"
  // if need to wait for infowindow to open
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
    console.log("that.id="+that.id)
    if (that.id === 1) {
      if (!!document.getElementById("des"+that.id))
        document.getElementById("des"+that.id).style.display = "none";
    }
  });
  this.infoWindow.setContent(content);
  this.infoWindow.open(map, this);
  // if domready has already fired
  if (that.id === 1) {
  if (!!document.getElementById("des"+that.id))
    document.getElementById("des"+that.id).style.display = "none";
  }

});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/94y9ewsb/59/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var markers = [];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.018057, 77.666794),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  function addMarker(feature) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: feature.position,
      map: map,
      type: feature.type,
      id: feature.id,
      title: "" + feature.id,
      description: feature.description,
      infoWindow: new google.maps.InfoWindow({})
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      // save this for use inside domready event listener callback function
      var that = this;
      var content = "<h5>" + this.type + "</h5>" +
        "<p id='des" + this.id + "'>" + this.description + "</p>"
      // if need to wait for infowindow to open
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
        console.log("that.id=" + that.id)
        if (that.id === 1) {
          if (!!document.getElementById("des" + that.id))
            document.getElementById("des" + that.id).style.display = "none";
        }
      });
      this.infoWindow.setContent(content);
      this.infoWindow.open(map, this);
      // if domready has already fired
      if (that.id === 1) {
        if (!!document.getElementById("des" + that.id))
          document.getElementById("des" + that.id).style.display = "none";
      }

    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }



  var features = [

    {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.018057, 77.666794),
      type: 'type1',
      id: 1,
      description: 'welcome to Hyd'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.015136, 77.647265),
      type: 'type2',
      id: 2,
      description: ' welcome to Blr'
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(13.009970, 77.660088),
      type: 'type3',
      id: 3,
      description: ' welcome to Mum'
    }

  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    addMarker(features[i]);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  initMap();
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working. Here I am getting "this.id" is "undefined".I am not able hide content if the id ==1.

Comment: I edited the answer to address your duplicate ids in the infowindow (although I didn't see that particular error)